# C#.NET Excel and OLEDB Connection String

Tags: c#

I am trying to read data from Excel file into my windows application.

Connection String :

```
provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = "Excel File"; 
Extended Properties =    \"Excel 8.0; HDR = Yes; ImportMixedTypes = Text;
Imex = 1;\"
```

With this connection string I am able to read data from Excel file **even though Microsoft office - Excel is not installed onto the computer**. But some how, my program is not compatible with this connection string.

Connection String which I am using right now is

```
provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = "Excel file"; 
Extended Properties = "Excel 12.0; HDR = Yes; Imex = 1;
```

This connection string is compatible with my program but **it only works on the computer which do have Microsoft office - Excel install.**

Can anyone suggest me where I am making mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it an xls or an xlsx?

Comment: I think the problem lies in the OLEDB Version you are using. Try researching this.

Comment: @Yatrix: I am trying to read both xls and xlsx.

Comment: Are you using straight ADO, or some other means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft removed the JET engine in all versions of Windows after 2003, including 64-bit Windows 2003.  ACE is the modern alternative, but it is not distributed with the base install of Windows either.

In order to use ACE, you need to deploy the free ACE redistributable from Microsoft to all target machines that do not have Office installed.  Then, you can use the second connection string you listed on any of them.

Get it from Microsoft here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Give me sometime I am trying to install this driver and would test my program

Comment: Be sure to read the instructions on that page, as well, as it provides specifics on connection strings.

Comment: +1 This man understands ACE does not come with Windows, like JET does.

Comment: I did tried on two different computer onto which Micorsoft Excel is not installed but result is same.

Comment: After spending couple of day finally I got a simple solution for my problem. Both connection do work and also driver which you have specify also work but not in all cases. I am just saving Excel file in 97-2003 format i.e. xls if it is .xlsx and everything seems work fine. thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Did you set the Extended Properties value to "Excel 8.0" when trying to work with a .xls file?  It must be 8.0 for .xls and 12.0 for .xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use third party libraries, there is a pretty nice project out there that offers the use of Linq to access excel files.  Check it out at : http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/